# How to know when WebView(or the whole gtk.Window) is fully rendered?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I found `'web-view-ready'`-signal and use it like this:

```
web = webkit.WebView()
web.connect("web-view-ready", finished)
```

But it never caught. May it is more simple to do it with gtk.Window signals?